# Overload of bittering hops, any "fixes"?

Tags: hops, all-grain, bitterness

I've had a 5 gallon all-grain batch of [John Palmer's Elevenses](http://www.northernbrewer.com/documentation/allgrain/AG-PalmersElevenses.pdf) in primary for just over a week. When I was brewing, I haphazardly dumped twice the prescribed amount of bittering hops (German Northern Brewer) in for the full 60 minutes. The recipe asks for 0.6oz, and I added the full 1oz sachet.

Upon testing the gravity last night I tasted the beer and it's very bitter, but otherwise good. Is there anything I can do, adjuncts I can add, hops I could add to secondary that might mask or "fix" this excessive bitterness I've induced? It's got a bit longer to go in primary before racking.

Comment: Meet up with the asker of this question, and blend? http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/13413/my-beer-has-little-to-no-hop-flavour-or-bitterness-what-is-going-wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. Time will reduce the bitterness somewhat, but not a great deal. If it's undrinkable, your best bet is to brew a second beer with very little hop bitterness and blend the two beers.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I suspected but I was hopeful for some sort of magic bullet solution. The beer is slated for NYE so it's probably too late in the game to make another blending batch.

Comment: The second glass usually tastes less bitter than the first. By the time you're on the eighth, you won't be bothered by it any more.

Answer (score 0):

If the taster was taken pre-ferment you might be shocked.  I always find wort to be very bitter and never an indicator of the final beers true bitterness.  When the yeast and trub settle post fermentation a good amount of bitterness goes with it and settles out bound to yeast and proteins.

Even beer that is still in fermentation will seem more bitter than the final product.

Wait and see...